# Outlook VSTO get Sender email and Sent time when email is sent

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I have a button in a ribbon that calls the below code. The purpose is to give employees a button to click that both sends the email and copies the contents to their clipboard. (long story short - have to paste all emails sent to clients into another system. I don't have access to just send the email straight there.)

Problem: I cannot get the sender name or actual sent time.

Assumption: I am guessing Outlook does not actually set that value until the send command is sent. Same for the sent time. (reason I used Date.Now).

Additional Info: A solution outside my initial instinct of adding a button to do both would be acceptable.

```
Public Sub OnTextButton(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem
    Dim email = "From: " & mailItem.Sender.Name & vbCrLf &
        "Sent: " & Date.Now.ToString("f") & vbCrLf &
        "To: " & mailItem.To & vbCrLf &
        "Subject: " & mailItem.ConversationTopic & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & mailItem.Body
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(email)
    mailItem.Send()
End Sub
```

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct: the sender related properties are not set until the message is actually sent and moved to the Sent Items folder.

You can either

1. Run your code in the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder
2. Check the `Account.SendUsingAccount` property (can be null) and use `Account.SmtpAddress`. If the account is not set, you can assume that the very first account from the `Namespace.Accounts` collection is used.